# How to get USER access token, the same used in Graph API Explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having trouble getting the user access token via Facebook Login with JavaScript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus)

The token returned through this function in response.authResponse.accessToken is actually an app access token. With this cannot, i can't access public profiles like in Graph API Explorer, for example. https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/993673107328394 won't work like in Graph API Explorer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) is only for checking the status, [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) is what you need to authorized a user.

Here´s an additional blogpost with some detailed information about the login process with the JavaScript SDK: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/